# What is the purpose of "Title" in a Stack Overflow profile?

Tags: support, profile-page

I am completing my Stack Overflow profile. I don't see any information on what 'Title' means to my profile. What kind of info should I put there?

There isn't any description present on that page, and a Google search gives very irrelevant results.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I use that field as Job Title but I guess it is open for any interpretation as it isn't labeled when rendered.

Here is what I use it for:

[image]

And this is what you would end up with:

[image]

*Subheader* would also be a matching explanation I guess, for those who have no Job or Title or feel it is not of anyone's business what their title is.

Comment: Thanks. I think, for me the most relevent part of your answer is "it is open for any interpretation as it isn't labeled when rendered".

Comment: But the thing is the degree and the school name will not be visible thereafter. That's not good. Simply, the Title replaces them.

Comment: I like that feature. I don't have a school or degree, so can use a title instead. I think that may be why we have some freedom to interpret its purpose to suit different needs.